# Using multiple instance and Senders in django signals

Tags: django, django-signals

how can i use multiple instances and senders (different models) in django signals.

```
receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def create_comment_notification(*args, **kwargs):
    #comments  notifier
    comment = kwargs['instance']
    post = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        if comment.author != comment.post_connected:
            Notification.objects.create(
                assigned_to = post.author,
                group='NC',
                body=f"{comment.author} commented: {comment.content} on your post.",
                pk_relation=comment.id
            )
    else:
        if comment.author != comment.post_connected:
            Notification.objects.create(
                assigned_to = post.author,
                group='NC',
                body=f"{comment.author} commented: {comment.content}.",
                pk_relation=comment.id
            )
```

I notice it work but does not recognizes the POST model, it uses COMMENT only. How can i use the two models as senders. and for the code to recognize them separately.

Thank you